# How to set height width of jqModal?

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I am using jqModal plugin. Does anybody know how to set it's height and width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried specifying height and width manually:

```
<div id="jqmd" class="jqmWindow" style="width: 400px; height: 260px"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when jqModal shows, there is this div and upon it a separate jqModal box appreas. If I adjust height of that div which is going to contain jqModal, then only div height is changed. Say if I shorten that div then it will appear that div ends below that jqModal window, but it's height is not changed

Answer (score 0):

In the jqModal.css file you can find this code:

```
.jqmWindow {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   top: 17%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -300px;
   width: 600px;
   background-color: #FFF;
   color: #333;
   border: 4px solid #8d8d8b;
   padding: 12px;
}
```

Replace the value of width with your needful value but make sure that you divide the value of your new width and that value will be your margin-left's value.
ex: width : 800 , margin-left: -400px